# Is it possible to use TypeORM and Angular 6

Tags: mysql, angular, typeorm

I am learning Angular 6 and have a question.

I have started developing with Angular 6 and I would like integrate TypeORM to manage entites for a MySQL database.

Is it possible and what should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: No not possible because Angular is a client side Javascript library which is not able to connect to a MySQL database.. You need to have a server side Javascript application like Node.js ( https://nodejs.org/en/ )

Comment: Also, you don't need it with Angular. I use it on the server with Nestjs.